# Errors while dynamic imports using importlib in python3

Tags: python-3.x, import, python-import, python-importlib, dynamic-import

I have been trying to use `importlib` with python3 (3.6).

**Directory structure**

*main.py*

```
#Note: I will only modify line 4 that uses importlib
import importlib
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("In main.py")
    hello = importlib.import_module('hello', package='./')
    print("Loaded hello.py")
    hello.hello()
```

*hello.py*

```
def hello():
    print('Hello world')
```

*folder/hello.py*

```
def hello():
    print('Hello world in folder')
```

**Observations**

If I do

`hello = importlib.import_module('hello', package='./')` or

`hello = importlib.import_module('hello')`

It imports *hello.py* from the root folder and prints `hello world`.

If I do

`hello = importlib.import_module('folder.hello')`

It imports *folder/hello.py* from the root folder and prints `hello world in folder`.

But if I do

`hello = importlib.import_module('hello', package='folder')` or

`hello = importlib.import_module('hello', package='./folder')`

It gives error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    hello = importlib.import_module('hello', package='./folder')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hello'
```

**Problem**

I am not sure what is going on here. I am pretty sure there is something wrong with my understanding of python modules and packages. Can someone explain why this is the expected behavior?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the first argument, the module to be imported is an absolute module reference ( has no leading `.`), the seond argument is completely ignored.

To import a module `a` relative to another module `b`, you have to use

```
a = importlib.import_module('.a', package='b')
```

In your case, this should work

```
hello = importlib.import_module('.hello', package='folder')
```

As a rule of thumb, `import package` should work if you want to use `package` as second argument.

```
from package import module
```

then becomes

```
importlib.import_module(module, package)
```

Comment: `importlib` is beyond what I can understand I guess. I upvoted your answer but now 
`importlib.import_module('math.sin')` or `importlib.import_module('.sin', package='math')` doesn't work.

Comment: @UmangGupta, that is because `sin` is a function in math module and and it is not a module itself. You need to do `math . = importlib.import_module('math')` and then `math.sin` will work. The name is `import_module` and not `import_function`

Comment: @TarunLalwani  I think that makes sense. Thanks for pointing out.
Just FYI, this works
`importlib.import_module('random', package='numpy')` So in the actual question why would `hello = importlib.import_module('hello', package='folder')` this not work? why do I need `.hello`

Comment: Does `hello = importlib.import_module('hello', package='folder')` give you an error or does it just loads the base module?

Comment: @TarunLalwani If I remove the `hello.py` in `.` folder, it gives `No module named 'hello'` error

Comment: @UmangGupta, unfortunately since you don't understand Mahesh's correct answer, I had to post a more detailed answer. Please have a look

Comment: Importing in Python is the biggest mess I have ever seen. It should be possible to import any function from any file, with a single line of code providing the path (absolute or relative, hard-coded or stored in a variable) to the file.

Comment: How can i get the current package name so it's always guaranteed to work?

Answer (score 4):

@Mahesh's answer is 100% correct and spot-on, but I guess we need to go one level deep to make you understand it better

Below is the code for `import_module`

```
def import_module(name, package=None):
    """Import a module.

    The 'package' argument is required when performing a relative import. It
    specifies the package to use as the anchor point from which to resolve the
    relative import to an absolute import.

    """
    level = 0
    if name.startswith('.'):
        if not package:
            msg = ("the 'package' argument is required to perform a relative "
                   "import for {!r}")
            raise TypeError(msg.format(name))
        for character in name:
            if character != '.':
                break
            level += 1
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
```

You can see if the `name` doesn't start with `.` then `if` part doesn't get executed. You just have `return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)` which gets executed with `level=0` as the value

Now let's get into that function, which has below code

```
def _gcd_import(name, package=None, level=0):
    """Import and return the module based on its name, the package the call is
    being made from, and the level adjustment.

    This function represents the greatest common denominator of functionality
    between import_module and __import__. This includes setting __package__ if
    the loader did not.

    """
    _sanity_check(name, package, level)
    if level > 0:
        name = _resolve_name(name, package, level)
    return _find_and_load(name, _gcd_import)
```

Again in this it just executes `_find_and_load(name, _gcd_import)`, now because `level` is `0` from our previous code, the `package` parameter is not being passed or used at all by `_find_and_load` method. Now you can easily verify this by running below

```
import importlib
hello = importlib.import_module('hello', package='IAmNotAfolder')
hello.hello()
```

And it will print `Hello World` from the base `hello.py`

So as you can see the `package` parameter is not used at all when the name doesn't start with `.`, which is for relative imports. That is why you get an error `No module named 'hello'` because it is trying to import `hello.py` from base folder irrespective of what you have in package.

Hope this answer make it easier for you to understand what is happening behind the scenes

Comment: 1. Yeah I just realized `importlib.import_module('random', package='numpy')` imported the `random` module from python and not `numpy.random`. I feel dumb about this now.
2. I guess `find_and_load` does not search in `system.path` but only loaded packages right? 
3. Thanks for putting the code out. I agree with Mahesh's observation, I got confused with `numpy` and `sys` examples :/

Comment: @UmangGupta, it is loading the package if it is not loaded and returning you the object. But it doesn't add it to your local/global scope. So if you don't take the return value into the variable you will have to call it using something like `sys.modules['hello'].hello()`

Comment: I am not sure about that. 

If I do `linalg=importlib.import_module('scipy.linalg')` It works, but `linalg = importlib.import_module('.linalg', package='scipy')
` this won't. This `import scipy; linalg = importlib.import_module('.linalg', package='scipy')
` works.

Comment: Not sure what you meant by contradiction :-|

Comment: I think it is the version issue.. works in 3.6 but not in 3.4. Anyways thanks very much for all the help.